# Can't pass slices of structs implementing the Foo interface to a function that expects []Foo

Tags: go, interface

I'm trying to work with interfaces in Go but I can't seem to be able to pass a slice of structs implementing a certain interface to a function that expects a slice of the interface. It works with functions that just takes a single object but not with functions expecting slices of the interface. Using the code below I get the following error:

> ./main.go:27: cannot use fooBar (type []*FooBar) as type []Foo in argument to FooBarBar

Here is the code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo interface {
    Bar() bool
}

type FooBar struct {
    a bool
}

func (f *FooBar) Bar() bool {
    return f.a
}

func FooBarBar(foos []Foo) {
    for _, foo := range foos {
        fmt.Println(foo.Bar())
    }
}

func main() {
    fooBar := make([]*FooBar, 2)
    fooBar[0] = &FooBar{true}
    fooBar[1] = &FooBar{false}
    FooBarBar(fooBar)
}
```

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Comment: Thanks! This is a good solution. Too bad it's necessary though...

Comment: It's helpful if you don't think of Go interfaces as type classes, but rather as pairs of (type,struct) where the "type" has a set of dynamic "virtual" pointers to the struct's implementation functions (if that makes sense!).   The assignment operator '='  automatically creates these representations  as necessary.  But it doesn't support slices - that is - it won't go through and represent that pair for each slice element.  (The actual implementation is somewhat similar, but not exactly what I'm describing, currently...)

Comment: Great explanation @BadZen! Given this.. Is there a good way to make a function like FooBarBar work regardless of whether the objects passed are of type *FooBar or Foobar (since there is no way for the function to know if the interface was implemented like "func (f *FooBar)..." or "func (f FooBar)...". I hope you understand my question.

Comment: Or more simply, the memory layout is different. `[]*FooBar` is a slice of pointer values, and `[]Foo` is a slice of 2-word interface values. One is not assignable directly to the other.

Comment: @JimB, see my question above. Is there any good solution for this?

Comment: @CrashproofCode: that's a different question, but not usually one that matters, since you can't compile with a value for an interface that doesn't already satisfy that interface. In your example here, just start with a `[]Foo` rather than `[]*FooBar`.

Comment: You could use generic `interface{}` type arguments, and then use rtti / type conversion to conditionally process either a `[]*FooBar` in the usual way, or a `[]Foo` by iterating and converting as we've talked about above.   I hope this instinctively strikes you as a /terrible idea/, however. =)

Comment: (Note that you are free to subtype slice types, and have those new types implement a common interface!   This may or may not be a terrible idea, depending...)

Answer (score 1):

There is no "sub typing" in Go.

`[]Foo` and `[]*Foobar` are 2 different types, so all you can do is use a for loop to convert `[]*Foobar` into `[]Foo`

```
foos := []Foo{}

for _,f:=range foobar {
    foos = append(foos,f)
}

FooBarBar(foos)
```

Or you can put your *Foobar directly in a slice of Foo :

```
foos := []Foo{&FooBar{true},&FooBar{false}}
FooBarBar(foos)
```

There are a few exceptions like the relationship between named types and unnamed types

```
type FooBar struct{}

type Foobars []*FooBar // Foobars is an named type, []*FooBar is an unnamed type

AcceptFoobars := func(f []*FooBar) {} // Accepts Foobars too

foobars := Foobars{{}, {}, {}}
AcceptFoobars(foobars)
```

Go type system is "flat", there is no inheritance or casting, only assertions and conversions. as defined by the Go spec.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types

> A type determines the set of values and operations specific to values
>   of that type. Types may be named or unnamed. Named types are specified
>   by a (possibly qualified) type name; unnamed types are specified using
>   a type literal, which composes a new type from existing types.

Comment: What is it called if you do define a type such as `type FooSlice []Foo`, if not "subtyping" then?   (This is an actual and not rhetorical question - I've always called this a "subtype" but if there is an official/better word for it...)

Comment: (Also it's worth mentioning embedding in a thread where you say "no inheritence" - it along with some language syntactic sugar provides something roughly similar to a sort of type inheritance.   See https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding)

Answer (score 0):

Can i try this way:

```
func main() {
    fooBar := []Foo{&FooBar{true}, &FooBar{false}}
    FooBarBar(fooBar)
}
```

[GoPlayGround](https://play.golang.org/p/0Mw9CkvR79):